# Drop in performance after upgrade to Sql Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

Recently I upgraded one of my databases from SQL 2003 to SQL 2016.

However, what I notice now is that those queries which were completing under 2 minutes on SQL 2003 are now taking over 4 minutes to complete. I was hoping that the upgrade would improve the performance.

I have also migrated the database from windows server 2007 to Windows 10.

Any clues on what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: **A lot** has changed in 13 years. Not least the cardinality estimator. I would not be surprised if you likely have a lot of poorly written queries that need visiting and rewriting. You could start by making the database(s) use the old cardinality estimator, and seeing how that effects performance.

Comment: There was not SQL Server 2003 nor Windows Server 2007. In my experience, which aligns with the comment by @Larnu, it is not uncommon for queries in need of tuning or indexes perform even worse after an upgrade. Check the query plans of problem queries for performance improvement opportunities.

Comment: SQL Server 2003? I must have slept through that one.

Comment: Could be that your statistics are out of date and need updating.